# Google analytics with a CMS - code is there but not "working"

Tags: content-management-system, google-analytics

I am using a less well known CMS called Ushahidi.

Within the settings of this CMS there is the option to add GA tracking by entering the web property I.D. (e.g.UA-340xxxx1-1).

The tracking code is then added to the site but it does not "fire".

Here is the code that appears after adding GA tracking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxx-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = TRUE;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

        </script>
```

I am not familiar with javascript but it appears to be the exact same as the code generated within the Google Analytics console.

Here is the URL: http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr

I do not understand why the code is not tracking?

Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tracking because the code that Ushahidi is injecting is not correct.

If you run debugging on the site you will see the error on line 743:

[image]

```
ga.async = TRUE;
```

That is your problem. It should be `ga.async = true;`. Javascript is case sensitve.

See [Tracking Basics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/).

I would recommend adding the code yourself and alerting them to the problem.